# How to show mongodb data as JSON? (NodeJS)

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

So what I'm asking is how I would show my MongoDB data as JSON on a seprate page? So far I have a database called 'movies' which has a table that contains a bunch of movie titles, rating and stock.

**As seen here:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e579d30bb58af007d4d8f3"), "movieTitle" : "Iron Man", "rating" : "Excellent", "stock" : "Yes", "sort" : "iron man", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e59c3d1d19a3d20ae67a9c"), "movieTitle" : "A Bittersweet Life", "rating" : "Poor", "stock" : "Yes", "sort" : "a bittersweet life", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e59c441d19a3d20ae67a9d"), "movieTitle" : "A Team", "rating" : "Okay", "stock" : "No", "sort" : "a team", "__v" : 0 }
```

**I also have the page I want the json to be displayed on:**

```
var express  = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router   = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('data', {});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Schema:**

```
var movieSchema = new Schema({
  movieTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  rating: {
    type: String
  },
  stock: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  sort: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you defined your model and schema inside mongoose?

Comment: Have you registered the model? e.g. `mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this:

```
var express  = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router   = express.Router();
var movieSchema = new Schema({
movieTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  rating: {
    type: String
  },
  stock: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  sort: {
    type: String
  }
});
var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema, 'movies');
mongoose.connect('localhost', function(err, res){
})

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Movie.find({}, function(err, movies) {
    res.render('data', movies);
  })
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: One small suggestion: skip passing 'movies' to a 'data' view and just res.json(movies);

Comment: Why do I need to include a new schema? I can't get this working, get erros when I do npm start.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who want to see how I got it working:**

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Get Movie schema for use
  var Movie = mongoose.model('movie');

  // Query all records using aggregate
  Movie
    .aggregate()
    .match({})
    .sort({ sort: 1 })
    .exec(function(err, movies) {
      // Handle errors
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({
            error: err
          });
      }

      // Manipulate movies to tidy up keys
      movies.forEach(function (movie) {
        movie.id = movie._id;

        delete movie._id;
        delete movie.__v;
        delete movie.sort;
      });

      return res.json(movies);
    });
});
```